# Create sortable field in search result in Oracle UCM 11G

Tags: oracle-ucm

In a default Oracle UCM / ORACLE URM instalation only the Title and Date fields are sortable (Click on header to change order).

How do I include a custom field that is sortable on the search result ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some instructions from [Kyle's Blog on WebCenter Content](https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/expanding_on_the_sort_fields_i):

> In order to add additional fields, it takes a simple component that
>   merges a couple of tables into the standard search definitions tables.
>   Those two additional tables are SearchEngineRules and SearchFieldInfo.
>
> In the custom SearchEngineRules table, you want to add the additional
>   fields to the pipe delimited list of sort fields.